# How to write binary data in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say there is a variable in a Bash script with the value "001". How can I write this binary data into a file as bits (as "001" not "1")

`echo` writes it as a string but I want to write in bits.

Comment: You can't write individual bits to a file. The smallest amount you can write is 8 bits, i.e. a byte.

Comment: how do i write 8 bit string variable say "00000011" to file

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne `printf '%s' $'\x03' > file`

Comment: @123 This works, but only as long as the value is not `\x00`, as this value can not be represented as an argument. `printf '\x00'` works though, since it avoids passing binary data literally

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can write arbitrary bytes in hex or octal with:

```
printf '\x03' > file   # Hex
printf '\003' > file   # Octal
```

If you have binary, it's a bit tricker, but you can turn it into octal with:

```
printf '%o\n' "$((2#00000011))"
```

which of course can be nested in the above:

```
binary=00000011
printf "\\$(printf '%o' "$((2#$binary))")" > file
```

Note that this only works with up to 8 bits. If you want to write longer values, you have to split it up into groups of 8.

Comment: what is the difference between writing in decimal and octal both are writing bytes

Comment: The result is the same, the difference is only in how you specify the byte you want to write. If you want to write all ones, it's `\xFF` vs `\377`. You can use whichever you prefer to work with.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `%b` in the printf:

```
printf "%b" "\012"
printf "%b" "\x0a"
```

> %b - Print the associated argument while interpreting backslash
>   escapes in there

so, above both prints binary value for the decimal `10`.

```
printf "%b" "\x0a" | od -bc
```

output

```
0000000   012                                                            
          \n
```

you can even mix

```
printf "%b" "\12\xa\n" | od -bc

0000000   012 012 012                                                    
          \n  \n  \n
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of more general functions to output integers to a file:

```
le16 () { # little endian 16 bit;  1st param: integer to 2nd param: file 
  v=`awk -v n=$1 'BEGIN{printf "%04X", n;}'`
  echo -n -e "\\x${v:2:2}\\x${v:0:2}" >> $2
}

le32 () { # 32 bit version
  v=`awk -v n=$1 'BEGIN{printf "%08X", n;}'`
  echo -n -e "\\x${v:6:2}\\x${v:4:2}\\x${v:2:2}\\x${v:0:2}" >> $2
}
```

Comment: Is awk really helpful here?
Using plain printf seems much cleaner to me: `v=$(printf "%04X" "$1")`

Answer (score 1):

Using **bc** (in CentOS 7.4):

```
VALUE="3F"
INPUT_BASE=16
OUTPUT_BASE=2
printf "%b\n" $(bc <<< "ibase=$INPUT_BASE; obase=$OUTPUT_BASE; $VALUE")
```

**RESULT**: 111111

If leading zeros are needed then:

```
VALUE="3F"
INPUT_BASE=16
OUTPUT_BASE=2
printf "%16b\n" $(bc <<< "ibase=$INPUT_BASE; obase=$OUTPUT_BASE; $VALUE") | sed 's^ ^0^g'
```

**RESULT**: 0000000000111111

*Note the use of 16 in the printf format; change value to limit leading-zero count*

Answer (score 1):

Most often you want to write a pattern (for instance a 32 bit pattern).

```
# Write 32 bits 5 times to a file 
for i in {1..5}
do
   printf '\x12\x34\xAC\xCD' >> binaryfile.bin
done
```

Another example:

```
for i in {1..255}
do
    hx=$( printf "%x" $i )
    output="\x$hx\x00\x00\x00"
    printf "%b" $output >> binaryfile.bin 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed this recently, someone might find it useful :

```
#!/bin/bash

# generate bitmasks for a C array

# loop counter
NUMBER=0
MAX_BITMASK_LENGTH=8
# max loop value : 2^8 = 255
MAXVAL=$((2**MAX_BITMASK_LENGTH))
# line number
LINE=0

# echo start of C array
echo "    const long int bitmasks[${MAX_BITMASK_LENGTH}] = {"

# loop over range of values
while [ ${NUMBER} -le ${MAXVAL} ] ; do

    # use bc to convert to binary
    BINARY=`echo -e "obase=2\n${NUMBER}"| bc`

    # print current number, linenumber, binary
    printf "%12s, /* (%i) %8s */\n" ${NUMBER} ${LINE} ${BINARY}

    # increase loop value to next value
    NUMBER=$(((NUMBER*2)+1))

    # increment line number
    LINE=$((LINE+1))
done

# echo end of C array
echo "        };"
```

This outputs:

```
$ ./generate_bitmasks.sh
    const long int bitmasks[8] = {
           0, /* (0)        0 */
           1, /* (1)        1 */
           3, /* (2)       11 */
           7, /* (3)      111 */
          15, /* (4)     1111 */
          31, /* (5)    11111 */
          63, /* (6)   111111 */
         127, /* (7)  1111111 */
         255, /* (8) 11111111 */
        };
```