# How do I export a string of bytes as an environment variable in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am encountering this error when I try to export a string of bytes as an environment variable. I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479826/how-do-you-set-a-string-of-bytes-from-an-environment-variable-in-python) and was able to set the variable using bash script, but when I try to add the variable to the Run configurations in pycharm I get this error;

[Error when trying to access the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuWeI.png)

Here are values I tried with for **Environment variables** field;

```
SECRET_KEY='\x06IP\xd0\x89\x8fU\x0b\xee\x85:\xe8x\xa6\xa6,\x88\xc6YU%&\xee\xcao\xca\xa0\xba\xbdo\xf2?'

SECRET_KEY=\x06IP\xd0\x89\x8fU\x0b\xee\x85:\xe8x\xa6\xa6,\x88\xc6YU%&\xee\xcao\xca\xa0\xba\xbdo\xf2?

SECRET_KEY=b'\x06IP\xd0\x89\x8fU\x0b\xee\x85:\xe8x\xa6\xa6,\x88\xc6YU%&\xee\xcao\xca\xa0\xba\xbdo\xf2?'

SECRET_KEY=$'\x06IP\xd0\x89\x8fU\x0b\xee\x85:\xe8x\xa6\xa6,\x88\xc6YU%&\xee\xcao\xca\xa0\xba\xbdo\xf2?'
```

None of them worked. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the secret key should a string rather than bytes.
You can base64 encode the bytes to get a string.

For example from a Linux terminal:

```
python -c 'import os;print(os.urandom(32))' | base64
```

Then use the generated encoded string as the SECRET_KEY